# Spring jsp Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'

Tags: java, jsp, modal, spring-mvc

Olá pessoal to com o seguinte erro quando tento excluir algo da minha tabela

```
WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Tenho um botão que deveria passar a id da linha selecionada para o value do campo hidden no modal para confirmar a exclusão segue abaixo:

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Endereço</th>
            <th>Vagas</th>
            <th>Preço</th>


        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${estacionamentos }" var="e">
            <tr>
                <td>${e.nome }</td>
                <td>${e.endereco }</td>
                <td>${e.vagas }</td>
                <td>${e.preco }</td>

                <td>
                    <c:url value="/estacionamento/editar/${e.codigo }" var="link"/>
                    <a href="${link}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>

                    <button  onclick="codigo.value = ${e.codigo}" type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirModal">
                        Excluir
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

modal:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="excluirModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirmação</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Realmente deseja excluir o estacionamento?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <c:url value="/estacionamento/excluir/" var="action"/>
        <form action="${action }" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="codigo" id="codigo">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando ao invés do hidden eu uso um campo text ou number e passo uma id manualmente a exclusão ocorre normalmente, gostaria de saber se estou usando o evento onclick da maneira correta ou se é outro erro que estou cometendo.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo indica que o erro está na passagem do código para o modal.

Tenta assim:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Endereço</th>
        <th>Vagas</th>
        <th>Preço</th>


    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${estacionamentos }" var="e">
        <tr>
            <td>${e.nome }</td>
            <td>${e.endereco }</td>
            <td>${e.vagas }</td>
            <td>${e.preco }</td>

            <td>
                <c:url value="/estacionamento/editar/${e.codigo }" var="link"/>
                <a href="${link}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>

                <button  onclick="passValueToModal(${e.codigo})" type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirModal">
                    Excluir
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

  //Poe isso dentro de <head></head> ou após o </jsp>
    <script>
    function passValueToModal(codigoSelecionado) {
        document.getElementById("codigo").value=codigoSelecionado;
    }    
</script>
```